# SwiftUI - Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<Int>' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
if(!user.hiddenUsersString.contains(String(meme.userid) + ",")){

}
```

I get

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<Int>' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'
```

on `String`

what the hell is this? It worked without errors until yesterday.

Why is swift such a pile of garbage :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a `Binding` to a `String` init. You need to pass the `wrappedValue` of the `Binding` instead.

```
String(meme.userid.wrappedValue)
```

This definitely couldn't have worked in its current form until yesterday. You probably replaced the `Int` property with a `Binding<Int>` and that's what introduced the issue.

> Why is swift such a pile of garbage :/

It isn't. You just made a mistake :)

Comment: No I didn't I swear, the only thing that I had to change is memes to $memes in                                 ForEach($memes, id: \.memeid){
                                    meme in which also worked until yesterday without the $. Ofc it is, not even JAVA is so unintuitive and disgusting. Thanks

Comment: @EduardUnruh well `$memes` is a `Binding`, so you did change the variable from an `Int` to a `Binding<Int>`, just didn't realise it.